# When it becomes working for free

Tags: pay-rate

How do I phrase an email requesting more money when I've already accepted a specific budget? The client is asking for more time than I would have expected to spend asking for revisions upon revisions and well past the initial deadline. It's a new client.

Comment: What does your contract say? If your contract stipulates a finite number of revisions, then you'd be able to charge for additional revisions, based on your contract. If your contract doesn't state anything regarding revisions, then you now know what sort of language to add to your next contract ;)

Comment: No formal contract only an email exchange agreeing to a flat rate based on a project deadline of one week ago. Can I not argue that extra time going forward will result in additional charges?

Comment: You can certainly try. Have you received any payment for work done so far?  If you're going to ask for more money, you should use the words "change of scope".  You may also have to chalk this up to "lessons learned" - I think most of us freelancers have one of those projects in our past.

Answer (score 3):

If you have yet to agree that extra work is billable then learn for your next contract. "One round of revisions and two weeks post delivery bug fixes for work agreed at the outset. All other out of scope changes shall be billed at my hourly rate of x ..."

You could try the tactic for now of I will take these revisions listed and deliver next Friday. After that any changes are new work. 
That way you are swallowing it allowing good grace but being firm. It's hard some times. Esp when clients start thinking of you as coworkers and just drift reply to you.

Comment: Thanks Tristan, I agree whole-heartedly. It seems this is a design by committee scenario. Always fun. <--can you hear my sarcasm? J